# Perl @INC Path Help

Tags: linux, perl

I got handed over a Perl script which fails to run because the path to the Perl is deleted.
How can I modify the path such that I can point it to /opt/perl/lib/5.28.2
Any help will really be appreciated. Huge thanks in advance.

```
[root@server1 ~]# perl -V
Can't locate Config.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Config module) (@INC contains: /xyz/perl/lib/site_perl/5.28.2/x86_64-linux /xyz/perl/lib/site_perl/5.28.2 /xyz/perl/lib/5.28.2/x86_64-linux /xyz/perl/lib/5.28.2).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
[root@server1 ~]# perl -e "print \"@INC\""\
/xyz/perl/lib/site_perl/5.28.2/x86_64-linux /xyz/perl/lib/site_perl/5.28.2 /xyz/perl/lib/5.28.2/x86_64-linux /xyz/perl/lib/5.28.2
[root@server1 ~]#


[root@server1 ~]# yum install perl
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo\
Package 4:perl-5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 already installed and latest version\
Nothing to do\
[root@server1 ~]# whereis perl
perl: /usr/bin/perl /opt/perl/bin/perl /usr/share/man/man1/perl.1.gz
[root@server1 ~]#
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go by a clean installation route, then uninstall first:

```
# yam remove perl
# yam install perl
```

For a single module you will need to do an upgrade (although will not work for Config.pm, since it describes the perl itself and part of the base package). But sometimes useful for additional libraries:

```
# cpan
> upgrade SomeModule
```

If you cannot do this, you can make use of PERLLIB environment variable. Find where the missing .pm is, and add that path into PERLLIB:

```
# export PERLLIB=/somepath:$PERLIB
```

You would need to add that line into your own or global profile.

If all you need is execution of some single script, you can modify it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib '/somepath'; # now this path is in @INC and modules from it can be used
```